# Output to data report to multiple txt files

Tags: python

I am trying to print multiple data sets to separate txt files. But when I run it, it is all reported in a single txt file (formatted as shown below). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
i=0
n=len(MZ_end)
with open ('test2{}.txt'.format(i), "w")as f:
    while i < n:    
        print ("MZ_start_(m/z):",MZ_start[i],'\n'
        'MZ_end_(m/z):', MZ_end[i],'\n'
        'RT_start_(minutes): 0', '\n'
        'RT_end_(minutes): 100', '\n'
        'DT_start_(m/z):',DT_start[i],'\n'
        'DT_end_(m/z):', DT_end[i],'\n',file=f)

        i+=1
```

test20.txt contains the following, I expected each paragraph to go in a separate file (test21.txt, test22.txt, and so on).

> MZ_start_(m/z): 1762.3817
>   MZ_end_(m/z): 1922.7802
>   RT_start_(minutes): 0
>   RT_end_(minutes): 100
>   DT_start_(m/z): 29.0
>   DT_end_(m/z): 41.0
>
> MZ_start_(m/z): 2366.5488
>   MZ_end_(m/z): 2521.6006
>   RT_start_(minutes): 0
>   RT_end_(minutes): 100
>   DT_start_(m/z): 46.0
>   DT_end_(m/z): 59.0
>
> MZ_start_(m/z): 3505.3767
>   MZ_end_(m/z): 3767.3606
>   RT_start_(minutes): 0
>   RT_end_(minutes): 100
>   DT_start_(m/z): 91.0
>   DT_end_(m/z): 111.0

Comment: I edited your question to make it more clear that the output should go to separate files instead of all to the same file. I also slightly reformatted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to swap your loop/file opening lines to get the desired effect:

```
i=0
n=len(MZ_end)
while i < n:    # <-- this one and the next one
    with open ('test2{}.txt'.format(i), "w")as f:
        print ("MZ_start_(m/z):",MZ_start[i],'\n'
        'MZ_end_(m/z):', MZ_end[i],'\n'
        'RT_start_(minutes): 0', '\n'
        'RT_end_(minutes): 100', '\n'
        'DT_start_(m/z):',DT_start[i],'\n'
        'DT_end_(m/z):', DT_end[i],'\n',file=f)

        i+=1
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly!! I wasn't expecting an answer so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally swapped the `open` and `while` lines. That means your current code  opens the file `test20.txt` once and then your data to that one file.

I would rewrite this as follows:

```
for i in range(len(MZ_end)):
    with open ('test2{}.txt'.format(i), "w") as f:
        print(..., file=f)
```

Alternatively, you can use `zip` to read from your arrays in parallel:

```
for i, mz_start, mz_end, dt_start, dt_end in zip(range(len(MZ_end)), MZ_start, MZ_end, DT_start, DT_end):
   ...
```